# PHP Form Handling fetching data from input values but not showing up on mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

I am relatively new to PHP and SQL, so as you can imagine I am beyond confused when it comes to creating a database and adding to the database with SQL and PHP. Basically, I am just running a test right now, to see whether I can add values to a table in my database with the input from my html. I have successfully connected the PHP file to my database and table, but, When I check my table the rows are blank. If you could check out my code to see what I am doing wrong I would really appreciate that!.

**This Is My HTML Form**

```
<form action='test.php' method='get'>    

  <input type='name' id='name' requiredtype='text'  name='name' 
  style='position: fixed; left: 200px; top:400px;'>

  <input type='email' id='email' requiredtype='text' name='email' 
  style='position: fixed; left: 200px; top:420px;'>

  <input type='submit' style='position: fixed; left: 200px; 
  top:440px;'>

</form>
```

**This is my test.php code**

```
<?php 
  $name = ($_POST['name']);
  $email = ($_POST['email']);


  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "...";
  $password = "...";
  $dbname = "...";

  // Create connection
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  } else if($conn) {
      echo 'Good Work Your Connected!';
  }

  $sql = "INSERT INTO nameEmailTable (Name, Email)
  VALUES ('$name', '$email')";

  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
     echo "New record created successfully";
  } else {
     echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
  } 

  $conn->close();
?>
```

The Connection does work fine, it is just the input of data that is not working.

Comment: You never define `$name` or `$email`. And, even of you did, you'd be wide open to SQL injections.

Comment: @JohnConde again this is just a test, I am aware of the fact that this is insecure. I defined $name and $email, when I wrote $_POST('name');

Comment: I could be wrong Im not sure

Comment: @JohnConde Sorry, I just realised. I have edited it and it still doesnt work.

Comment: "just a test" is not an excuse for insecure code. Code that "starts" as a test commonly ends up being used in the real world. *Always* start with security in mind regardless of how you plan to use your code.

Comment: @JohnConde I understand this, but thats not my question

Comment: The security you don't want to do could be the cause of your problem. You could be SQL injecting yourself.

Comment: why exactly have you wrapped the values of your PHP variables in brackets like `($_POST['email'])`?

Comment: @JohnConde my website is a blank screen with 1 form, I dont think anyones going to want to sql inject me

Comment: @JohnConde I thought thats what you were meant to do? Do I take the brackets away

Comment: That's exactly why you'll be an easy target for attack

Comment: @JohnConde can you please just tell me why my variables arent working

Comment: @JohnConde what is the purpose in wrapping variables in brackets like `$name = ($_POST['name']);`?

Comment: Does anyone know why it isnt working?

Comment: @DatBoiTrump are the actual column names in your table capitalized? im a n00b at MySQL and PHP too but that could be the issue

Comment: Yes they are @Anthony

Comment: @DatBoiTrump what is the purpose of wrapping variables in brackets like `$name = ($_POST['name']);`? have you tried removing `(` and `)` from your variable declarations?

Comment: @Anthony yes I have tried to remove them nothing happens

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of wrapping them in brackets like that?

Comment: I saw in a video tutorial that someone did it, but I am not sure why. I have removed the brackets anyway

Comment: Have you checked to see of those values exist? What does `var_dump($_POST);` show?

Comment: Also, are you getting any errors or "new record created successfully"?

Comment: @JohnConde what do I do with `var_dump($_POST);` do. Where do I put it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your first line in the form.

You have

```
method='get'
```

It must be

```
method='post'
```

Then you will receive the data into the $_POST array.